# GNU parallel export function output to variables failed

Tags: variable, function, gnu-parallel

This script is to determine when destination file already exist, source file will update the destination one or be removed according to flag "$dup_act".

```
#!/bin/bash
dup_chk()
{
  # $1: f_src, $2: f_dest, $3: dup_act (keep file u/pdate, l/arge)
  # check source file and destination file status 
  
  [[ "$3" = u && $(stat -c%Y "$1") -gt $(stat -c%Y "$2") || "$3" = l && $(stat -c%s "$1") -gt $(stat -c%s "$2") ]] \
  && echo -e "$1~$2~\n" >> mv_f.tmp || echo -e "$1\n" >> rm_f.tmp
  
  # mv_f.tmp: a list of source file replace destination one
  # rm_f.tmp: a list of source file to be removed
}

[[ -f mv_f.tmp ]] && rm mv_f.tmp ; [[ -f rm_f.tmp ]] && rm rm_f.tmp

dup_act=u # or dup_act=l

export dup_act
export -f dup_chk
cat dup_files.txt |  parallel -j10 --no-run-if-empty --colsep '~'  dup_chk {1} {2} "$dup_act"
```

The output files `mv_f.tmp` and `rm_f.tmp` are generated correctly.

Now, I want to the script output variables instead of files:

```
#!/bin/bash
dup_chk()
{
  # $1: f_src, $2: f_dest, $3: dup_act (keep file u/pdate, l/arge)
  # check source file and destination file status 
  
  [[ "$3" = u && $(stat -c%Y "$1") -gt $(stat -c%Y "$2") || "$3" = l && $(stat -c%s "$1") -gt $(stat -c%s "$2") ]] \
  && mv_f+="$1~$2~\n" || || rm_f+="$1\n"
  
  # mv_f: a variable of source file replace destination one
  # rm_f: a variable of source file to be removed
}

mv_f= ; rm_f= 

dup_act=u # or dup_act=l

export dup_act
export -f dup_chk
cat dup_files.txt |  parallel -j10 --no-run-if-empty --colsep '~'  dup_chk {1} {2} "$dup_act"
```

The result:  `$mv_f` and `$rm_f` variables are empty.

I found out in other post: "Environment variables can only be passed from parent to child (as part of environment export/inheritance), not the other way around.". Is this the reason?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Does `dup_chk` work as expected when not run with GNU Parallel? Also appending to the same file in parallel often ends in race conditions.

Comment: With or without GNU Parallel, ```dup_chk``` works well to generated the output files ```mv_f.tmp``` and ```rm_f.tmp```. When I try to replace the output from files to variables ```$mv_f``` and ```$rm_f```, it failed and both variables are empty. That is why I need help. :)

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel spawns jobs in shells. Think of it as:

```
bash -c 'the job'
```

You cannot get variables back from that:

```
i=1
bash -c 'i=2'
# prints 1
echo $i
```

You add values to an array in the `bash -c` part and this will not make it back to the parent.

But you might be able to change your script so that you can use `parset`.

```
# NB: parset will not work correctly if reading from a pipe
parset myresults dup_chk < dup_files.txt
```

and then do some postprocessing on `myresults`.

Comment: Thank you for your great work on GNU_parallel.  I will read more about the parset since I just learned GNU_parallel a few days ago.  It has saved me almost half the time to convert jpg to heic and I do have a lot of jpgs.  Many thanks.